# GetRawInputDeviceList not working as expected on Windows7

Tags: winapi

I ran into the following problem: Using GetRawInputDeviceList in C# or C++ produces different results in Win8 vs Win7. I took a C++ example ran it in Win8 and did get appropriate results where it did not in Win7 latest patch level.
So I took an old Win7 image (no patches applied) and ran the example against it - and it produced expected results.

```
        // ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream>

    // Namespace
    using namespace std;

    // Main
    int main()
    {
      // Program
      cout << "USB Device Lister." << endl;

      // Get Number Of Devices
      UINT nDevices = 0;
      GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &nDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

      // Got Any?
      if (nDevices < 1)
      {
        // Exit
        cout << "ERR: 0 Devices?";
        cin.get();
        return 0;
      }

      // Allocate Memory For Device List
      PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList;
      pRawInputDeviceList = new RAWINPUTDEVICELIST[sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)* nDevices];

      // Got Memory?
      if (pRawInputDeviceList == NULL)
      {
        // Error
        cout << "ERR: Could not allocate memory for Device List.";
        cin.get();
        return 0;
      }

      // Fill Device List Buffer
      int nResult;
      nResult = GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, &nDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

      // Got Device List?
      if (nResult < 0)
      {
        // Clean Up
        delete[] pRawInputDeviceList;

        // Error
        cout << "ERR: Could not get device list.";
        cin.get();
        return 0;
      }

      // Loop Through Device List
      for (UINT i = 0; i < nDevices; i++)
      {
        // Get Character Count For Device Name
        UINT nBufferSize = 0;
        nResult = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInputDeviceList[i].hDevice, // Device
          RIDI_DEVICENAME,                // Get Device Name
          NULL,                           // NO Buff, Want Count!
          &nBufferSize);                 // Char Count Here!

        // Got Device Name?
        if (nResult < 0)
        {
          // Error
          cout << "ERR: Unable to get Device Name character count.. Moving to next device." << endl << endl;

          // Next
          continue;
        }

        // Allocate Memory For Device Name
        WCHAR* wcDeviceName = new WCHAR[nBufferSize + 1];

        // Got Memory
        if (wcDeviceName == NULL)
        {
          // Error
          cout << "ERR: Unable to allocate memory for Device Name.. Moving to next device." << endl << endl;

          // Next
          continue;
        }

        // Get Name
        nResult = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInputDeviceList[i].hDevice, // Device
          RIDI_DEVICENAME,                // Get Device Name
          wcDeviceName,                   // Get Name!
          &nBufferSize);                 // Char Count

        // Got Device Name?
        if (nResult < 0)
        {
          // Error
          cout << "ERR: Unable to get Device Name.. Moving to next device." << endl << endl;

          // Clean Up
          delete[] wcDeviceName;

          // Next
          continue;
        }

        // Set Device Info & Buffer Size
        RID_DEVICE_INFO rdiDeviceInfo;
        rdiDeviceInfo.cbSize = sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO);
        nBufferSize = rdiDeviceInfo.cbSize;

        // Get Device Info
        nResult = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInputDeviceList[i].hDevice,
          RIDI_DEVICEINFO,
          &rdiDeviceInfo,
          &nBufferSize);

        // Got All Buffer?
        if (nResult < 0)
        {
          // Error
          cout << "ERR: Unable to read Device Info.. Moving to next device." << endl << endl;

          // Next
          continue;
        }

        // Mouse
        if (rdiDeviceInfo.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
        {
          // Current Device
          cout << endl << "Displaying device " << i + 1 << " information. (MOUSE)" << endl;
          wcout << L"Device Name: " << wcDeviceName << endl;
          cout << "Mouse ID: " << rdiDeviceInfo.mouse.dwId << endl;
          cout << "Mouse buttons: " << rdiDeviceInfo.mouse.dwNumberOfButtons << endl;
          cout << "Mouse sample rate (Data Points): " << rdiDeviceInfo.mouse.dwSampleRate << endl;
          if (rdiDeviceInfo.mouse.fHasHorizontalWheel)
          {
            cout << "Mouse has horizontal wheel" << endl;
          }
          else
          {
            cout << "Mouse does not have horizontal wheel" << endl;
          }
        }

        // Keyboard
        else if (rdiDeviceInfo.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
        {
          // Current Device
          cout << endl << "Displaying device " << i + 1 << " information. (KEYBOARD)" << endl;
          wcout << L"Device Name: " << wcDeviceName << endl;
          cout << "Keyboard mode: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwKeyboardMode << endl;
          cout << "Number of function keys: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwNumberOfFunctionKeys << endl;
          cout << "Number of indicators: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwNumberOfIndicators << endl;
          cout << "Number of keys total: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwNumberOfKeysTotal << endl;
          cout << "Type of the keyboard: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwType << endl;
          cout << "Subtype of the keyboard: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwSubType << endl;
        }

        // Some HID
        else // (rdi.dwType == RIM_TYPEHID)
        {
          // Current Device
          cout << endl << "Displaying device " << i + 1 << " information. (HID)" << endl;
          wcout << L"Device Name: " << wcDeviceName << endl;
          cout << "Vendor Id:" << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.dwVendorId << endl;
          cout << "Product Id:" << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.dwProductId << endl;
          cout << "Version No:" << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.dwVersionNumber << endl;
          cout << "Usage for the device: " << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.usUsage << endl;
          cout << "Usage Page for the device: " << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.usUsagePage << endl;
        }

        // Delete Name Memory!
        delete[] wcDeviceName;
      }

      // Clean Up - Free Memory
      delete[] pRawInputDeviceList;

      // Exit
      cout << endl << "Finnished.";
      cin.get();
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen, what did actually happen, how did that fail to meet your expectations?

Comment: I expect a devicelist especially keyboards. Not happening on Win7 as described. You can take the C++ sample. If no result - "ERR: Unable to get Device name".

Comment: "Unable to get Device name" means `GetRawInputDeviceInfo()` is failing, but you are not reporting *WHY* it is failing. Use `GetLastError()` to find out.